# Java Database Object

Tags: java, database

If I have a program that stores info on members in a database is it ok to create an entire arraylist of the systems members when I want to do tasks or would take be too time consuming? Or should I just find the cells in the database that I need for specific members or specific columns or would this way be too messy?

Comment: The only reasonable answer is that it depends... On the number of members, on the type of "tasks" you need to perform (could they be performed at the DB level?), etc.

Comment: Instead of wondering about the performance of the system, measure it.  Use an ORM for simplicity of data access and see if the performance is within acceptable limits.  Optimize the use of the ORM.  If further performance tweaks are needed, optimize with some more direct database access, micro-optimizing only as needed.  Keep in mind that sometimes saving hours (or days, weeks, months, etc.) of development time is worth *a lot* more than saving milliseconds of system time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite general; what the best thing to do is depends on what the program needs to do exactly.

However, in general, it is not a good idea to just select all rows from a table, especially if there are very many rows in the table, and then try to find the rows your need in Java code (by looking through the list).

It's better to tell the database what rows you need by sending it the appropriate SQL query, so that the database returns exactly the data the program needs. Relational databases are made specifically and optimized for that job.

Comment: I read the question differently (unclear as it is, I admit).  I thought he was asking "should I select all columns for a given row, or only the ones I need" rather than "should I select all rows and filter in code".

Comment: If I need the email of all members with a certain id then would I just create the member objects of all the members with that ID and add them to an arraylist and just go through the arraylist and check for the emails? Or just go through the table and check the emails and make member objects for the right ones?

Comment: @R00059159 Create an SQL statement to get the exact data that you would need. Something like `select email from members where id=...`, then let your Java program send that query to the database and get the results.